# Why is Elon Musk building the Starship first?

Tags: spacex-starship, spacex-super-heavy

I mean what is he going to do with the ship alone? Is it even capable of orbital flight on its own?

Now the booster can be put to use immediately, and will probably be easier to make by far (I think)? Although, seeing how much use falcon heavy has seen, I don't know about the demand about such a powerful rocket ATM, but they can at least launch big batches of StarLink satellites, I guess...

So, what are SpaceX plans?

Here are some Starship and SuperHeavy pictures, just for fun:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is SpaceX building the Big Falcon Ship before the Big Falcon Rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25968/why-is-spacex-building-the-big-falcon-ship-before-the-big-falcon-rocket)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Starship alone is not capable of orbital flight, but it is capable of high suborbital flights sufficient for testing reentries.

The booster's only use is as a first stage for Starship. It could only be put into use immediately if a Starship has been developed and built to stack on top of it. And it is expected to be much quicker and easier to develop than Starship:

- It is simpler in terms of aerodynamics and thermal protection than Starship because it doesn't need to do the belly flop maneuver or return from orbit.
- It won't ever go anywhere near orbit, only giving Starship a few km/s before separating and returning, so it won't have any orbital refueling equipment.
- Far less work needs to be done on mass optimization: every kilogram added to Starship is a kilogram taken from payload, but a kilogram added to Superheavy is a kilogram taken from the combined Starship + payload + full propellant load, with a much smaller impact to the payload.

All this means that if they started Superheavy first, they'd have it sitting around idle for the entire program to develop Starship.

Developing the booster first would also more tightly constrain Starship's design, because they'd have to go back and redesign Superheavy to make any major changes. This was an issue for Orion/Ares-I, where they developed the booster first, but ran into problems getting the upper stage and capsule light enough to reach orbit on it. Another similar issue was Starliner, which was developed to launch on the existing Atlas V and Centaur upper stage. Some aerodynamics issues arose late in development that required an "aeroskirt" be added to protect the Centaur during launch.

By starting Starship first, they'll be able to run it through a suborbital test program and further iterations of design refinements while building the Superheavy booster, they'll know exactly what Superheavy has to lift, and they'll be ready to start full orbital flights when Superheavy's done.

Comment: Why would the booster's only use be for Starship?  Surely you could use it to launch any heavy payload.

Comment: This answer comes very close, but I think it's worth saying more explicitly--being "much more constrained" in the Starship design means that Starship's mass gets constrained, and there's nothing an aerospace project loves to do more than gain mass.  Something like the reverse happened during Constellation, where the boosters (particularly Ares I-X) were designed early on and then Orion's mass spiraled out of control and all kinds of problems resulted.

Comment: @jamesqf sure, it can launch any heavy payload that mechanically fits the Superheavy upper stage mounting and separation hardware and which needs to be launched to a low suborbital trajectory. Here's a comprehensive and complete list of such payloads: Starship.

Comment: @ErinAnne You forgot "gain budget"!

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- monetary budget, time budget, mass budget, they're all good.

Comment: Nice answer, but perhaps the most important point could be stressed more: Super Heavy is a *first stage*, so it's entirely useless without a matching second stange. It simply can't replace Falcon (9/Heavy) or launch Starlink satellites at all.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: That seems like a complete cop-out.  IF there was a super-heavy booster, you could stick a second stage (or even a third) on top of it, and launch heavier planetary exploration probes, moon base or space station components, or whatever.  Which is not to say that it might not be cheaper to do those with multiple smaller launches...

Comment: @jamesqf To do that, *you need a second stage*. That's Starship, and only Starship. This isn't a cop-out, *nothing else will work*.

Comment: If you're looking at Huff's "that's Starship" without context I can totally understand that not seeming correct, but literally any second stage for Super Heavy at this point is Starship.  That's the system SpaceX has declared they're working on (including passenger, cargo, and tanker variants proposed).  The Starship is the thing they *want* to fly; Super Heavy is practically support equipment.

Comment: The widest diameter second stage currently available would be the Delta IV DCSS. This is a little over half the diameter it'd need to be, and even with its maximum payload is around 1/25th the mass that Superheavy is designed to lift. It uses hydrogen fuel which isn't supported by the Starship launch pads, and since it isn't designed to stage at ~3 km/s, it would just fall into the ocean after separation. You need a 9 m ~1.5 kt methalox upper stage that stages at around 3 km/s. No such thing exists, and Starship is the only one under development.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: Why?  I know of no reason why 2nd and later stages need to be the same diameter as the first.  Indeed, here's an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V  Fairings and adapters should be simple.

Comment: @jamesqf: I think you're asking the wrong question. The booster is designed for Starship, and the design will be changed to match Starship. Adding a second design constraint for a different upper stage will hinder development at this point. Once the booster is built however, and the design is stable, it becomes possible to build alternative upper stages. We're far from that point. SpaceX typically designs iteratively, so the booster design is nowhere near stable.

Comment: @jamesqf okay, now they're spending engineering time on an adapter to use...what stage, exactly? Give just one example of an existing stage that would actually work with Superheavy.

Comment: I'd like to add that this approach - do the hard, high-risk stuff first - is a principle of Lean Manufacturing and Lean Software development, which clearly inform SpaceX processes.

Comment: I would like to add that most of the steps they're currently taking to develop starship directly apply to the superheavy booster as well.... The diameter is the same, the tanks will be extremely similar.... There's no engineering time wasted by working on starship. On the other hand there's a huge loss in potential testing time by not having starship ready sooner.

Comment: @MSalters: I think it's more a question of viewpoint.  If you're Elon Musk, taking your vehicle designs from 1950s SF magazine covers, it perhaps makes sense to build a single-purpose booster.  If you're a SpaceX shareholder, perhaps not so much.

Comment: @jamesqf it has nothing to do with "taking vehicle designs from 1950s SF magazine covers". Launch vehicles rarely support more than one second stage, and when they do it's typically minor variations of the same stage, like the 4 and 5 meter Delta IV upper stages. And again, *what alternate stage are they going to support*?

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: Re Musk's design sources, I draw your attention to the 2nd image in the question, particularly the September and December 2018 versions.  WRT the second stage question, just because something has been done one way in the past doesn't mean that it has to be done that way in the future.  Adapting for different stages would seem not much more of a technical challenge than adapting for different payloads.

Comment: @jamesqf **What "different stages"?**

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: Anything someone wants to put on top of a big first stage.

Comment: @jamesqf There. Aren't. Any. Disagree? **NAME ONE.**

Comment: @Christopher James Huff : There. Isn't. A. BFR. Booster. Either.  The point is that it could be built, and second stages could be built and/or adapted to it, allowing it to do something useful.  SpaceX could then charge customers for the use of it, unlike the Starship, which even if it works, seems to serve no useful purpose.

Comment: @jamesqf SpaceX needs a booster for Starship and that's what they're building. Nobody else has upper stages that would be able to use such a booster. It's clear you have some kind of problem with this, but it's the simple truth. You **can not** just throw a second stage on any booster and expect the stack to work. If you can't see why, ask your own question on the topic. And if you don't see a use for dramatically lower launch costs and the ability to send 100+ t to anywhere from LEO to the surfaces of the moon and Mars, ask one about that...maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: Nobody could possibly want to launch large chunks of a space station or lunar/planetary mission?  You're the one that seems to have problems, since you just implied that there would be a market for launching 100+ tons.

Comment: @jamesqf Superheavy is completely incapable of delivering anything to orbit without Starship. It is not a SSTO launch vehicle. Again, ask your own questions. I will not respond to you again here.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff: Baloney!  It is just as capable of being the first stage of a launch vehicle as for instance the Saturn V first stage was.

Answer (score 9):

In simplified terms, the list of minimum requirements for completing the missions Starship is set to do is much longer and more complex than that for Superheavy. For Earth Orbit or Lunar missions, the Starship absolutely needs to:

1. Launch
2. Perform orbital insertion
3. Rendezvous and Dock
4. Maintain life support / functionality in long-term spaceflight
5. Orbital Refuel (Lunar only)
6. Perform a new and dangerous entry/descent/landing sequence

The Superheavy booster, though, only has one absolutely necessary function, launching. Reuse for both of these vehicles, while essential for long-term financial success, is unnecessary for near-term operational use. The Superheavy's boostback and landing is very similar to Falcon 9's, which further reduces schedule risk due to unanticipated developmental delays.

As for other considerations for vehicle development like materials and assembly processes, SpaceX is hashing out all its metallurgy and welding problems on the Starship prototypes, and the optimal solution from that can be copied for the Superheavy.

Comment: Orbital refueling is also needed for Mars missions and for direct GEO insertion or delivery of large payloads to GTO (without refueling in LEO, it actually has lower payload to GTO than Falcon Heavy). On the other hand, lunar flybys, or deployment of independent lunar landers, can be done without refueling.

Answer (score 6):

> I mean what is he going to do with the ship alone?

Develop it. Test it. Verify it. Perform suborbital flights.

Remember that SpaceX is also toying with the idea of offering point-to-point passenger service on Earth. (Personally, I believe that will not happen, though.)

> Is it even capable of orbital flight on its own?

No, but for testing launch and landing you don't need to go to orbit.

> Now the booster can be put to use immediately,

The booster can be used for exactly one thing: launch Starship. If they don't have a working Starship yet, the booster is useless.

> and will probably be easier to make by far (I think)?

Yes. SpaceX have always had the maxim to tackle the hard problems first, which is another reason to focus on Starship first.

> Although, seeing how much use falcon heavy has seen, I don't know about the demand about such a powerful rocket ATM, but they can at least launch big batches of StarLink satellites, I guess...

The biggest commercial use of the Starship system in the beginning will indeed be Starlink. The Starship system can launch almost seven times as many satellites per launch (400 instead of 60) as Falcon 9 can. This brings the number of launches for the planned first batch of 12000 satellites down from 200 to just 30. In total, SpaceX has just filed for another addition which (if they use everything they filed for) would bring the total number of satellites up to 42000, which would require only 105 launches on the Starship system instead of 700 on Falcon 9.

However, some commercial customers that have booked launches on Falcon Heavy have already given permission to launch on the Starship system instead, and looking further out, SpaceX will retire the whole Falcon line in favor of the Starship system. It *should* be cheaper since it is 100% reused and will land very close to the launch pad and not require the ASDS. (The only reason to keep the Falcon 9 for a limited amount of time would be to bridge the time where Starship is operational, but not yet human-rated, so they need to keep F9 around for Crew Dragon.)

Comment: SpaceX intends to replace Falcon 9 with Starship, not just Falcon Heavy. Just the Falcon second stage costs about 3-4 times what the operational costs of Starship are expected to be.

Comment: "*point-to-point passenger service on Earth*" At which point it's appropriate to remember that a "point-to-point payload service on Earth" is the definition of an ICBM.  I'm not saying Elon Musk is definitely Hugo Drax, but it's ironic that this could make Donald Trump's otherwise-batshit-crazy Space Force plans a justifiable concept.

Comment: @Graham If you're looking at it that way, then there's nothing new here. SpaceX has had "point-to-point payload delivery" capability since Dragon returned from orbit in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

The breakthrough idea and most demanding engineering task of Starship/SH is complete re-usability of the orbital vehicle. If you tried to reach orbit with Super Heavy alone-- it's not designed for this and so I'm not sure it's even possible-- it would just be a large expendable booster, which might well be more expensive to operate than the partially-expendable F9.  Amost all the difficulty, and so required development time, as well as value lie in Starship as a reusable orbital second stage. Therefore it is natual that that is where SpaceX puts their initial development work.

Comment: SuperHeavy will be expandable, are you sure?

Comment: @NikolaiFrolov if you tried to reach orbit with it alone, it certainly would be.

Comment: @NikolaiFrolov the SH is intended to be reusable as a booster. But what antlersoft is saying is: if you use it for other purposes, it wouldn't be reusable. Eg, it can't do reentry from orbit.

Answer (score 2):

An important point to understand: it is not as simple as "just put this stage on that booster." Real life is more complicated than Kerbal Space Program. There is a lot of design, test, and certification work that has to be done before using a certain stage combination -- time that is better spent working on Starship -- so the SuperHeavy booster is not really useful until Starship is finished, and Starship is the harder part of the two so SpaceX chose to start with it.

Answer (score 0):

### It's not about using Starship by itself.

One reason I remember Musk saying in an interview or something somewhere is that the starship is much more difficult to design and much higher risk, obviously since it has to do much more, while the super heavy is much more like a scaled up falcon 9 booster. So they started with the more difficult and higher risk part, which will take longer to finish. Super heavy can be designed in a shorter period of time, so presumably they can start with that at a time such that both are ready more or less at the same time. And by doing the high risk parts first, they will find out earlier if there is something that needs to be radically changed, and not have a large wasted investment in the super heavy.

A second reason is that the super heavy requires 31 raptor engines while the starship only requires 6 or so, and only 3 for atmospheric flight. Their production rate of raptor engines isn't high enough yet to have all those engines ready, so better wait with the super heavy until enough engine production capacity is available.

(And Starship has barely enough thrust to lift itself when the vacuum engines are also used, which might be useful in an emergency escape scenario but not for any regular operation. So ideas about Starship flying to places by itself are non-starters.)